# Is this a Banana leaf plant?

Tags: houseplants, banana

We have a plant that we considered to be [birds of paradise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strelitzia) for last 4 years.

[image]

Yesterday in a brief bout of lucidity we realized that it might be Banana leaf plant
, since it never gave flowers and is ~6ft tall. [Searching doesn't really](https://perennialpastimes.com/2015/04/08/birds-or-bananas-strelitzia-musa-and-heliconia/) help, but that seems to be a common problem to distinguish these two species.

The main issue we have is that it is not very short, leafs are not too round, the stems looks like birds'.

If this is a birds of paradise plant, how can we make in flower indoors? We have plenty of sunlight and can afford larger pot.